# Creating .resource file in windows forms

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am trying to create a .resource file which will contain all the strings being used in the application. I don't want to do it manually.

I know there are certain [ways](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/resources/creating-resource-files-for-desktop-apps) to do it. But my problem is, I don't want to have it done manually, where I need to add each string resource. Is there a way to do this without I having to put each string, and it automatically detects all the strings resources corresponding to different pages.

Any insights on this would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to do this.

You can try with [R#](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/), although the tool is commercial, there is a 30-days trial period.

As a regular user, I can tell you that it worth every cent.

There are suggestion for every string, and moving to the resource file is accomplished by one click.